# Charles vs Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion, charles-proxy

So I'm using genymotion on a MacBook Pro. I've launched Charles, where I got my Local Address and Proxy Port (transparent proxying enabled) and I set up on the Emulator settings. I've added a Manual Proxy with the settings that Charles providing.

Apart from all my efforts, I can't see my Emulator traffic, only the Macbook. Sometimes Charles changing the IP address, but this is just an addition :) 
If any of you have ever faced with a similar problem, I would like to ask for your help. I made the basic settings, but still can't see my traffic in Charles. Any suggestions please?

Comment: this is a yes/no question, I suggest you rephrase it to reflect better what it really is you want to know

Comment: I agree with @TimCastelijns

Comment: But if you want to see Emulator traffic, you should set your Macbook to be a bastion, to broadcast a wifi network for the emulator to connect to. Then, sniffing the broadcasted wifi, you should be able to wireshark only emulator traffic.

Comment: thanks guys, rephrased the question.

Comment: Exact same problem here and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you set the proxy from the Android device and not from Genymotion software?

Open a Genymotion device then go to the WiFi settings, open the current wifi connection item, check the advanced settings checkbox and then you can set your Charles proxy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I follow [this](http://rexstjohn.com/using-genymotion-charles-proxy/) and it worked.

Set your Genymotion Android emulator's Wifi Proxy to: `10.0.3.2:8888`

P.S. My Genymotion version is 2.11.0